# How to monitor the features called in after scenario and after feature hooks?

Tags: karate

I am calling a feature file after-feature hook . 
It is mentioned in the readme that

```
# one limitation of afterScenario and afterFeature is that any feature steps involved will NOT appear
```

So how to check whether anything has failed in the feature file called in after-feature hook?
One possibility is to use karate.log file , but is there any other way to generate reports for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way, print to the log.

You can also create a feature file just to test this feature being called and debug that using the [Karate UI](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-UI).

It may be a better idea to use the yet undocumented Java hook, see this example [MandatoryTagHook](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/MandatoryTagHook.java)